# How to simplify a foldLeft operation on boolean elements?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I use this method to determine if a string is all upper case.

```
def isAllUpperCase(s: String): Boolean = 
  s.foldLeft(true)((res, ch) => res && ch.isUpper)
```

IntelliJ warns that this operation on a collection can be simplified. Sadly, I'm a Scala noob. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `foldLeft`, consider this for a given string `s`,

```
(true /: s)(_ && _.isUpper)
```

or equivalently,

```
s.foldLeft(true)(_ && _.isUpper)
```

For this particular problem consider also `forall`, as follows,

```
"abc".forall(_.isUpper)
res: Boolean = false

"Abc".forall(_.isUpper)
res: Boolean = false

"ABC".forall(_.isUpper)
res: Boolean = true
```

namely, it evaluates to true only if each and every element scrutinised evaluates to true.

Then,

```
implicit class RichUppercase(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def allUpper() = s.forall(_.isUpper)
}
```

and so

```
"abc".allUpper
res: Boolean = false

"ABC".allUpper
res: Boolean = true
```

**Update**

Another approach relies on finding differences between the original string and that string uppercased, like this,

```
val a = "Abc"
a: String = abc

a diff a.toUpperCase
res: String = bc

a.toUpperCase diff a.toUpperCase
res: String = ""
```

so a resulting empty string means all characters in the string are uppercase.

Comment: I feel another important difference between `fold` and `forall` (or `exist`) here is that `fold` will evaluate every single character while `forall` will stop as soon as a non-matching one is found.

Answer (score 1):

You want `forall`:

```
def isAllUpperCase(s: String): Boolean = s.forall(_.isUpper)
```